# JavaScript WebGL add one color to each square

Tags: javascript, colors, 3d, webgl

I'm really new in WebGL and I looked for a high-detailed tutorial. But every example I saw contained other js libraries or used multiple color each side of the polygon. So this is the example I would like to change to set only one color for squares in the array.

```
var colors = [
   5,3,7, 5,3,7, 5,3,7, 5,3,7,
   1,1,3, 1,1,3, 1,1,3, 1,1,3,
   0,0,1, 0,0,1, 0,0,1, 0,0,1,
   1,0,0, 1,0,0, 1,0,0, 1,0,0,
   1,1,0, 1,1,0, 1,1,0, 1,1,0,
   0,1,0, 0,1,0, 0,1,0, 0,1,0 
];
```

It would be:

```
var colors = [
   5,3,7,
   1,1,3,
   0,0,1,
   1,0,0,
   1,1,0,
   0,1,0
];
```

The whole code is:

```
  <script>

     /*============= Creating a canvas ======================*/
     var canvas = document.getElementById('my_Canvas');
     gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');

     /*========== Defining and storing the geometry ==========*/

     var vertices = [
        -1,-1,-1, 1,-1,-1, 1, 1,-1, -1, 1,-1,
        -1,-1, 1, 1,-1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1,
        -1,-1,-1, -1, 1,-1, -1, 1, 1, -1,-1, 1,
        1,-1,-1, 1, 1,-1, 1, 1, 1, 1,-1, 1,
        -1,-1,-1, -1,-1, 1, 1,-1, 1, 1,-1,-1,
        -1, 1,-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,-1, 
     ];

     var colors = [
        5,3,7, 5,3,7, 5,3,7, 5,3,7,
        1,1,3, 1,1,3, 1,1,3, 1,1,3,
        0,0,1, 0,0,1, 0,0,1, 0,0,1,
        1,0,0, 1,0,0, 1,0,0, 1,0,0,
        1,1,0, 1,1,0, 1,1,0, 1,1,0,
        0,1,0, 0,1,0, 0,1,0, 0,1,0 
     ];

     var indices = [
        0,1,2, 0,2,3, 4,5,6, 4,6,7,
        8,9,10, 8,10,11, 12,13,14, 12,14,15,
        16,17,18, 16,18,19, 20,21,22, 20,22,23 
     ];

     // Create and store data into vertex buffer
     var vertex_buffer = gl.createBuffer ();
     gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
     gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

     // Create and store data into color buffer
     var color_buffer = gl.createBuffer ();
     gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, color_buffer);
     gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

     // Create and store data into index buffer
     var index_buffer = gl.createBuffer ();
     gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer);
     gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

     /*=================== SHADERS =================== */

     var vertCode = 'attribute vec3 position;'+
        'uniform mat4 Pmatrix;'+
        'uniform mat4 Vmatrix;'+
        'uniform mat4 Mmatrix;'+
        'attribute vec3 color;'+//the color of the point
        'varying vec3 vColor;'+
        'void main(void) { '+//pre-built function
           'gl_Position = Pmatrix*Vmatrix*Mmatrix*vec4(position, 1.);'+
           'vColor = color;'+
        '}';

     var fragCode = 'precision mediump float;'+
        'varying vec3 vColor;'+
        'void main(void) {'+
           'gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.);'+
        '}';

     var vertShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
     gl.shaderSource(vertShader, vertCode);
     gl.compileShader(vertShader);

     var fragShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
     gl.shaderSource(fragShader, fragCode);
     gl.compileShader(fragShader);

     var shaderprogram = gl.createProgram();
     gl.attachShader(shaderprogram, vertShader);
     gl.attachShader(shaderprogram, fragShader);
     gl.linkProgram(shaderprogram);

     /*======== Associating attributes to vertex shader =====*/
     var _Pmatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderprogram, "Pmatrix");
     var _Vmatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderprogram, "Vmatrix");
     var _Mmatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderprogram, "Mmatrix");

     gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
     var _position = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderprogram, "position");
     gl.vertexAttribPointer(_position, 3, gl.FLOAT, false,0,0);
     gl.enableVertexAttribArray(_position);

     gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, color_buffer);
     var _color = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderprogram, "color");
     gl.vertexAttribPointer(_color, 3, gl.FLOAT, false,0,0) ;
     gl.enableVertexAttribArray(_color);
     gl.useProgram(shaderprogram);

     /*==================== MATRIX ====================== */

     function get_projection(angle, a, zMin, zMax) {
        var ang = Math.tan((angle*.5)*Math.PI/180);//angle*.5
        return [
           0.5/ang, 0 , 0, 0,
           0, 0.5*a/ang, 0, 0,
           0, 0, -(zMax+zMin)/(zMax-zMin), -1,
           0, 0, (-2*zMax*zMin)/(zMax-zMin), 0 
           ];
     }

     var proj_matrix = get_projection(40, canvas.width/canvas.height, 1, 100);
     var mo_matrix = [ 1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1 ];
     var view_matrix = [ 1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1 ];

     view_matrix[14] = view_matrix[14]-6;

     /*================= Mouse events ======================*/

     var AMORTIZATION = 0.95;
     var drag = false;
     var old_x, old_y;
     var dX = 0, dY = 0;

     var mouseDown = function(e) {
        drag = true;
        old_x = e.pageX, old_y = e.pageY;
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
     };

     var mouseUp = function(e){
        drag = false;
     };

     var mouseMove = function(e) {
        if (!drag) return false;
        dX = (e.pageX-old_x)*2*Math.PI/canvas.width,
        dY = (e.pageY-old_y)*2*Math.PI/canvas.height;
        THETA+= dX;
        PHI+=dY;
        old_x = e.pageX, old_y = e.pageY;
        e.preventDefault();
     };

     canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
     canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
     canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseUp, false);
     canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove, false);

     /*=========================rotation================*/

     function rotateX(m, angle) {
        var c = Math.cos(angle);
        var s = Math.sin(angle);
        var mv1 = m[1], mv5 = m[5], mv9 = m[9];

        m[1] = m[1]*c-m[2]*s;
        m[5] = m[5]*c-m[6]*s;
        m[9] = m[9]*c-m[10]*s;

        m[2] = m[2]*c+mv1*s;
        m[6] = m[6]*c+mv5*s;
        m[10] = m[10]*c+mv9*s;
     }

     function rotateY(m, angle) {
        var c = Math.cos(angle);
        var s = Math.sin(angle);
        var mv0 = m[0], mv4 = m[4], mv8 = m[8];

        m[0] = c*m[0]+s*m[2];
        m[4] = c*m[4]+s*m[6];
        m[8] = c*m[8]+s*m[10];

        m[2] = c*m[2]-s*mv0;
        m[6] = c*m[6]-s*mv4;
        m[10] = c*m[10]-s*mv8;
     }

     /*=================== Drawing =================== */

     var THETA = 0,
     PHI = 0;
     var time_old = 0;

     var animate = function(time) {
        var dt = time-time_old;

        if (!drag) {
           dX *= AMORTIZATION, dY*=AMORTIZATION;
           THETA+=dX, PHI+=dY;
        }

        //set model matrix to I4

        mo_matrix[0] = 1, mo_matrix[1] = 0, mo_matrix[2] = 0,
        mo_matrix[3] = 0,

        mo_matrix[4] = 0, mo_matrix[5] = 1, mo_matrix[6] = 0,
        mo_matrix[7] = 0,

        mo_matrix[8] = 0, mo_matrix[9] = 0, mo_matrix[10] = 1,
        mo_matrix[11] = 0,

        mo_matrix[12] = 0, mo_matrix[13] = 0, mo_matrix[14] = 0,
        mo_matrix[15] = 1;

        rotateY(mo_matrix, THETA);
        rotateX(mo_matrix, PHI);

        time_old = time; 
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

        // gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);

        gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9);
        gl.clearDepth(1.0);
        gl.viewport(0.0, 0.0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(_Pmatrix, false, proj_matrix);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(_Vmatrix, false, view_matrix);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(_Mmatrix, false, mo_matrix);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer);
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

        window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
     }

     animate(0);

  </script>
```

Comment: How can I store the colors in array like above? So one color each polygon

Comment: You can use uniform attribute. **uniform vec3 colors[6];** Then just add an index for color in vertices array.

Comment: [Try these tutorials](http://webglfundamentals.org)